# Going back to login page after clicking a new link

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The code is working, no errors but does not do what I wanted it to do

I have the following state hook:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({name: ""});
```

on render I have:

```
<>    
  {(name != "") ? (
    <>        
      <Navbar />
      <div className='container'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
          <Route path="/List" element={<List />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </>
  ) : (
    <Login Log={Log} error={error} />
  )}      
</>
```

Logging in is Ok, I get to the `/` page but clicking a new link would bring me back to the sign-in form.

Comment: did you try to use ```exact``` prop in the Route component?

Answer (score 0):

As the page reloads the saved value of `name` gets initialized again with "".

You have to persist it somewhere. Maybe in the localstorage or a redux state. So that even if the page reloads the value is read form a persistent storage.